# Convert Shader to CIKernel

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, shader, cifilter

I'm trying to convert this particular shader to CIKernel Code.

https://www.shadertoy.com/view/4scBRH

I've got this soo far,

```
kernel vec4 thresholdFilter(__sample image, float time)
 {
 vec2 uv = destCoord();
 float amount = sin(time) * 0.1;

 amount *= 0.3;
 float split = 1. - fract(time / 2.0);
 float scanOffset = 0.01;

  vec2 uv1 = vec2(uv.x + amount, uv.y);
  vec2 uv2 = vec2(uv.x, uv.y + amount);
  if (uv.y > split) {
  uv.x += scanOffset;
  uv1.x += scanOffset;
  uv2.x += scanOffset;
}

float r =  sample(image, uv1).r;
float g = sample(image, uv).g;
float b = sample(image, uv2).b;
float a = 1.0;

vec3 outPutPixel = sample(image, samplerTransform(image, uv)).rgb;
return vec4(outPutPixel, 1.0);
 }
```

The output of this code is not even close to the shaderToy output.

Comment: Brad larson can help you out in this. He did similar kind of work in his GPUImage library.

Comment: In the Shadertoy source code, what does the code for `!VHS` (or the `else` part) do? Also, what does the output look like (or what do you mean by *"... is not even close..."*?

Comment: @dfd hello, Please take a look at this. https://github.com/abhiperry/cikernelDEMO

Comment: @AmritTrivedi, did you find a guide/docs to do this?

Comment: @AbhishekDave Did you solve this by chance? We trying to the same..